My external USB camera does not work with OpenCV, how do I fix it?
I wrote some code using cv2 but when I try to use my external webcam it doesn't work. I made sure that my camera is detected by the computer, and I can use it in the camera app, and I have tried changing the cv2.VideoCapture() from 0 to 1. I'm using VSCode. It doesn't throw any error, rather it runs indefinitley without opening any window.
import cv2

# Initialize the webcam (0 is the default webcam)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # If frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Webcam Live', frame)
    
    # Press 'q' to exit the window
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


"It doesn't work" isn't very helpful.  What happens?  Do you get an error?  Which error?

I think -1 could still work on Windows: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1).

Remove the break and find out what the symptoms are? What error message do you get?  Is the frame empty?  Use frame.shape to see if it returns 0s for the shape.

are you able to open the camera with VLC media player? Being able to open it with "the camera app" doesn't tell it could be compatible to any generalized way of access. What kind of app is it?

disabled camera app and try again

I was frustrated with getting the right number in VideoCapture, so I looped from 0 to 10 and checked if it is returning a frame or not (using ret). Try doing the same to get which index is working
